# TF2, Warning: Connection Problem, Auto Disconnect in x seconds

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2, macos

When i connect to any server, after 1-2 minutes i get notification at the right of the corner: "Warning: Connection Problem, Auto Disconnect in 25 seconds" and after 25 seconds it disconnects from server. I search in google for problem and tried all suggestions, problem still continues.

- I tried checking internet connection this issue happens, no problem in internet connection
- I tried port forwarding in my router for TF2
- I tried turning on/off firewall
- I tried restarting router/steam/game/mac
- Validated game files
- I tried changing router, changing internet connection
- Tried uninstall/install steam and TF2

Please help, i can't play the game

fyi, i playing game in mac book pro.

Comment: Open the console, then type `net_graph 1`. It should show you detailed information about your network connection.

Comment: @Sumurai8 fps: 60, in: 269, out: 70, ping: 100ms, it shows information like this

Comment: Your ping is slightly high, but not so high that it should matter. I am more interested in the choke and loss stats - and if the ping rises during these 2 minutes.

Comment: @Sumurai8 yes, ping is slightly high, but i don't think the reason for this problem is ping. Ping not rises when 'connection problem' message appears, i increased my timeout up to 300, but in this 300 seconds game does not reconnect, i wait until timeout finish. When i get 'connection problem' message, i checked my internet connection, no problem, i can surf in game browser of steam too,

Comment: @Sumurai8 check screenshot of net_graph info, http://imgur.com/sNay1Qf

Comment: @Sumurai8 here is the screenshot of net_graph when auto disconnect message appears http://imgur.com/t7Ci1To and here the proof that i have internet connection when "connection problem" message appears, http://imgur.com/ugC1TL5, please help solving this issue,

Comment: Looking at those screenshots, my best bet is that this is a firewall issue, dropping connections if they are maintained for too long. The stats as shown there look normal to me. Do you have access to your router's firewall rules?

Comment: @Sumurai8 yes, i tried turning off routers firewall too

Comment: Turning off the firewall entirely is a foolish thing to do. Is this a dedicated Valve server, or is an outside user hosting this?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf connection problem occurs in both, valve servers and community servers. I have Counter-Strike GO too on my steam account, connection problem message does not appear when I play CS GO.